# How to make looped function calls for pagination?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, pagination, offset

I am attempting to use the [Airtable API](https://airtable.com/api) to retrieve records from my data there - specifically, a list of URLs I have in column cells.

I wrote a function, `get_airtable_records`, to do the API call via `curl` and it works - returning results as a Json object. Specifically, I am pushing the URLs to an array, `$article_urls`.

The only problem is, Airtable limits the return of results to "pages" of a maximum 100 records, and my data contains more than that. The API accepts parameters `maxRecords` and `pageSize` but the more important one, `pageSize`, is still capped at 100.

What Airtable does also return is another Json value, `offset`, which is used in such cases for pagination. The `offset` is a record ID intended to be used as an input parameter (also called `offset`). **You can use it to denote the *starting* record in a subsequent additional API call. I understand this**.

What I don't understand is how to modify my code to account for the possibility of needing to poll Airtable again.

In other words, we should always do a starting run from scratch, when there is no `offset` value.
Then, if an `offset` value is present in returned results, we should go around again - until an `offset` value is not present.

Here is what I have.

```
  // Make get request, store result in array
  $articles = get_airtable_records($offset); // $offset won't exist at the start

  // Prepare Article URLs list as an array
  if (!isset($article_urls)) {
     $article_urls = array();
  }

  // For each URL found in Airtable
  foreach($articles['records'] as $record){
     $url = $record['fields']['Published URL'];
     // Add to our array list
     if (!empty($url)) {
        array_push($article_urls, $url);
     }
  }

  // URL list after first pass:
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($article_urls);
  echo '</pre>';
  // May hit a max of 100

  // echo 'Offset: ' . $articles['offset'];
  // Value like "itrJYSLx0RfslI80f/recEu6TiPTPCSDxg5" may exist.
  // If so, go back to start, do get_airtable_records($offset) again and array_push
  // Until, once more there is no "offset" value at end
```

I am speculating that some sort of `while` loop will be useful... ?

A couple of things are true...

- In the first call, there will be no originating `offset` value needing to be passed, since it starts from record 0.
- But that and subsequent passes may generate an `offset` value, which should be used to make another pass.
- The *final* call will not generate an `offset` value, since it will have returned the final page of exhausted results, and there is no need to start again.

Comment: This is a duplicate post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998254/getting-more-than-100-records-with-airtable/56178563#56178563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks largely to [@anthony's answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371408/1375163), I seem to have some working code...

```
  // Prepare Article URLs list as an array
  $article_urls = array();

  // Call Airtable records in pages of 100 max
  do {

        // Offset is either inherited from last page's results, or is nothing
        $offset = $articles['offset'] ?: "";

        // Make get request, store result in array
        $articles = get_airtable_records($offset);

        // For each URL found in Airtable
        foreach($articles['records'] as $record){
           $url = $record['fields']['Published url'];
           // Add to our array list
           if (!empty($url)) {
              array_push($article_urls, $url);
           }
        }

  } while(!empty($articles['offset'])); // If there's an offset value (ie. starting record of next page), do again

  // Output URL list for check
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($article_urls);
  echo '</pre>';
```

Explanation seems to be:

Use a `do` `while` loop.
At the start of this, set `offset` to be either the value inherited from the previous run, or nothing.

My `get_airtable_records` function was already limiting the presence or not of `offset` in the API call, with the following, which adds the `offset` query string to the URL for the next API call if one is present...

```
  if (!empty($offset)) {
    $q_offset = '&offset='.$offset;
  }
```

I have tested this and it gave me all 137 results from two pages in to my `$article_urls` array. I haven't tested it with any more than two pages of results.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive  anonymous functions also work well for an auto paginator.

```php
// http client
    $client
    // closure
    $autoPaginate = function (int $offset) use (&$autoPaginate, $client) {
        $response = $client->get('https://blah.com, [
            'offset' => $offset,
            'per_page' => 100,
        ]);
        // do response business logic/work
        
        // check your response meta or
        // wherever the next page or offset is passed back
        if (!$response->meta->next->offset) return;
        return $autoPaginate($response->meta->next->offset);
    };
    $autoPaginate(0);
```